# when to expect processor response code 2016 (Duplicate Transaction)?

Tags: braintree

I am unable to find when to expect processor response code "2016 Duplicate Transaction"? only when previously a similar transaction was successful ? or when processor has seen this transaction recently (even if it failed). in contrast to gateway rejection for duplicate transaction, which only happens when a previous similar transaction was successful. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, you can always [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

I originally misunderstood your question. Processors don't necessarily provide the specifics as to why they return a particular processor response. Your best bet is to reach out to Braintree support and see if they can provide any more information in this particular case.

My original answer about Braintree duplicate transaction checking follows.

---

A transaction will be rejected as a duplicate when you have [the duplicate checking option enabled and the following conditions are met](https://support.braintreepayments.com/customer/portal/articles/1429427-processing-options#Duplicate):

- Credit Card Number is the same
- Credit Card Expiration Date is the same
- Amount is the same
- Order ID is the same OR Subscription ID is the same
- Previous transaction was within X seconds (30 by default)
- Previous transaction was successful

Comment: these are the gateway rejection conditions. how about processor response code 2016? i am assuming here all the processing response codes are coming from processor, if my assumption is true then what conditions processor have to respond with this code?

Comment: @user3487149 Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer, but it may not be particularly helpful.